# Android: the app crashes if I run it on a device with API 24 or 25 (Nougat)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-permissions, android-virtual-device

I'm a novice Android developer experiencing some difficulties in **cross-version support**: I'm developing an app (the name is RECIPE) with minimum SDK version requirement of 21 (from Lollipop and on).

For now the app has just few features: it switches activities via intents, open the camera by sending an intent, allow the user to make a single photo with the camera module and then stores the photo and returns a preview back to the main app.

The problem occurs when the camera intent is called: in this case the app runs smooth if I run it on an emulator with a device with API 23 (Marshmallow; for 21 and 22 Lollipop's API now the app doesn't work because I have to do some permission managing); but unfortunately, **the app crashes if I run it on a device with API 24 or 25 (Nougat)**.

If you want to reproduce the problem, after having installed the app (on a physical or emulated device with API 24 or 25) open it, then click on "GO TO SINGLE PHOTO SHOOTING MODE" and then on "TAKE PHOTO" to start the camera intent.
Normally you will also be prompted of allowing writing permission to store the photo file.

I think that the bug comes from the writing permissions or from something regarding the camera intent.

Down here there is the code

**MainMenu.java**

```
package it.iudiconenext.alessandro.recipecrowdsourcingapp;


/**
 * TODO=check if AppCompatActivity is necessary
 */

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.pm.ActivityInfoCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


/** The main class with the one that extends and the implementation of the callback for the result
 * of requesting permission */
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity
implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    // Id to identify the Write External Storage permission request (it can be a random number)
    private static final int REQUEST_WES = 0;

    // The following string is used in log messages
    public static final String TAG = "MainMenu";

    /**Called when the activity is first created.*/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    }

    /** The button for going from the Main Menu Activity to the Single Photo Shooting Activity*/
    public void buttonMMAtoSPSA(View view) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Accessing to SPSA. Checking permission.");

    //Check if the Write External Storage permission is already available.
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Write External Storage permission is already available, show the SPSA.

        MMAtoSPSA();

    } else {
        // Write External Storage permission has not been granted.

        // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted and the
        // user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "External Storage Writing access is required.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Request Write External Storage permission
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WES);
    }
    }

    private void MMAtoSPSA () {
    //The part of the code for switching to Single Photo Shooting Activity
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, SinglePhotoShooting.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    /** The button for going from the Main Menu Activity to the Multi Photo Shooting Activity*/
    public void buttonMMAtoMPSA(View view) {
    //The part of the code for switching to Multi Photo Shooting Activity
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MultiPhotoShooting.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    //@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionResult (int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_WES){
        if (grantResults [0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.i(TAG, "WES permission has now been granted; continuing.");

            Toast.makeText(this, "WES permission has now been granted; continuing.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Log.i(TAG, "WES permission was denied; stopping.");
        }

    } else
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
    }

}
```

**MultiPhotoShooting.java**

```
package it.iudiconenext.alessandro.recipecrowdsourcingapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by alessandro on 09/06/17.
 * This is the Java Class corresponding to the "Multi Photo Shooting mode"
 */

public class MultiPhotoShooting extends AppCompatActivity{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.multi_photo_shooting);}

    /** The button for going from the Multi Photo Shooting Activity to the Main Menu Activity */
    public void MPSAtoMMA(View view){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainMenu.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
}
```

**SinglePhotoShooting.java**

```
package it.iudiconenext.alessandro.recipecrowdsourcingapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

/**
 * Created by alessandro on 08/06/17.
 * This is the Java Class corresponding to the "Single Photo Shooting mode"
 */

public class SinglePhotoShooting extends AppCompatActivity {

    // This variable is needed as request code in the takePhoto method
    private static final int ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP = 0;

    // This ImageView variable is useful for finding the view that we want inside the layout
    private ImageView SPSAPhotoTakenImageView;

    // A variable in the activity that saves the location of the file where we've written to
    private String mImageFileLocation = "";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_photo_shooting);
    SPSAPhotoTakenImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id. PrewievSPSA);
    }

    /** The button for going from the Single Photo Shooting Activity to the Main Menu Activity */
    public void SPSAtoMMA(View view){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainMenu.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    /** The method to call an Intent to open the camera app */
    public void SPSATakePhoto(View view) {
//        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SinglePhotoShooting,
//                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    Intent callCameraApplicationIntent = new Intent();
    callCameraApplicationIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // We give some instruction to the intent to save the image
    File photoFile = null;

    try {
        // If the createImageFile will be succesful, photofile will have the address of the file
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    // Here we call the function that will try to catch the exception made by the throw function
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Here we add an extra filed to the intent to put the address on to
    callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

    startActivityForResult(callCameraApplicationIntent, ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP);
    }

    /** The method to give a Bitmap back to the application for a preview */
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP && resultCode == RESULT_OK ){
        /** The code that handles the preview for the photo */
        // Here we create a bitmap and use BitmapFactory to decode the file
        Bitmap SPSAPhotoTakenBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageFileLocation);
        // Assign the bitmap to the ImageView
        SPSAPhotoTakenImageView.setImageBitmap(SPSAPhotoTakenBitmap);
    }
    }

    /** The function that specifies the location and the name of the file that we want to create */
    // As certain function calls quite important rights, we wanna catch and be notified when something goes wrong and for this we throw an exception
    File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Here we create a "non-collision file name", alternatively said, "an unique filename" using the "timeStamp" functionality
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmSS").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "IMAGE_" + timeStamp + "_";
    // Here we specify the location and environment where we want to save the so-created file
    File storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    // Here we create the file using a prefix, a suffix and a directory
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDirectory);
    // Here the location is saved into the string mImageFileLocation
    mImageFileLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();

    // The file is returned to the previous intent across the camera application
    return image;
    }

}
```

**activity_main_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="it.iudiconenext.alessandro.recipecrowdsourcingapp.MainMenu">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Activity_Main_Menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Main Menu"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/Activity_Main_Menu"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/TakePhotoButtons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ButtonMMtoSPSA"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:paddingTop="30dp"
                        android:onClick="buttonMMAtoSPSA"
                        android:text="Go to Single Photo Shooting Mode"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/ButtonMMtoMPSA"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:paddingTop="30dp"
                            android:onClick="buttonMMAtoMPSA"
                            android:text="Go to Multi Photo Shooting Mode"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**multi_photo_shooting.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Multi Photo Shooting mode"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonMPSAtoMM"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press me for going back to the Main Menu"
        android:onClick="MPSAtoMMA"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**single_photo_shooting.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Multi Photo Shooting mode"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonMPSAtoMM"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press me for going back to the Main Menu"
        android:onClick="MPSAtoMMA"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.iudiconenext.alessandro.recipecrowdsourcingapp">

    <!-- Permissions managing. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



    <!-- camera permission is unnecessary due to the use of an external resource
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
     -->

    <!-- Read permission is unnecessary due to the already present write permission
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    -->

    <!-- There is no need to access the location for the moment
    TODO: verify if giving this permission can give access to the GPS by the camera and so to photo
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    -->


    <!-- The following permission is needed only if your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or
     higher and uses GPS localization service.
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    -->


    <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="true"/>

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SinglePhotoShooting"
        android:theme="@style/PhotoTakingTheme"
        android:label="Single photo mode"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MultiPhotoShooting"
        android:theme="@style/PhotoTakingTheme"
        android:label="Multi photo mode"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance,
Alessandro

**EDIT 20/06/2017**: I think that the problem regards something about URI exceptions because I find the following article which states that these exceptions are given starting from android N versions and because in debugging my app I obtain this exception in return.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html

Comment: "the app crashes if I run it on a device with API 24 or 25 (Nougat)" -- please edit your question and provide the complete Java stack trace, along with the code referenced in that stack trace (so the question can be useful in the future, when the code at your GitHub repository changes).

Comment: It's a good idea and seems to be a better solution. I already changed the name of my question and regarding the java code I should have to edit it before posting (like removing some "todo" things and unuseful comments)...I will do this ASAP. Thanks

Comment: I've added also the code right now (and removed the link to the repository) and in the meantime I found an article that seems to describe my problem...I've added it in line to my original post. Now I'm trying to find a solution.

Comment: I do not see the complete Java stack trace, which was the most important thing that I asked for. If you are getting `FileUriExposedException`, you are running Android 7.0+ and an app with a `targetSdkVersion` of 24 or higher, and [the `file` `Uri` scheme is banned](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html). You are getting this from your use of `Uri.fromFile()`. Use `FileProvider` or something else to give you a `content` `Uri` to use instead.

Comment: Unfortunately the message goes over 30000 characters if I try to put in also the full (verbose) Java stack trace and so is not possible to include also that one into...anyway, I'm trying to fix this problem with the file Uri but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) demonstrating the use of `FileProvider` with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: Than you, the problem was exactly that one. Following some online resources, in particular this one [link] (https://rahulupadhyay.wordpress.com/2016/12/27/android-n-fileuriexposedexception/) I was able to solve the problem. Furthermore, I noticed that following some other online resources with ".fileprovider" instead of ".provider" in the string contained in the Manifest that declares the "Authorities" doesn't work (it works only with `android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"`). So the problem was the use of file Uri (banned). Do you suggest to delete the post or to keep it and reply?

Comment: " Furthermore, I noticed that following some other online resources with ".fileprovider" instead of ".provider" in the string contained in the Manifest that declares the "Authorities" doesn't work" -- so long as everything is consistent, and the resulting authority string is unique, the value does not matter. Most likely, you had an inconsistency, such as using `.fileprovider` one place and using `.provider` in another. "Do you suggest to delete the post or to keep it and reply?" -- I would vote "keep it and answer your own question with what worked for you".

Comment: Ok, thank you again...I'm preparing a comment with all the details needed for everyone in the community that will encounter the same need I had to solve the problem, with also a repository along... I think to post the answer in this evening if everything goes fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**: Find out that the problem was about the way in which I was trying to manage files from one app (the main app) to the other (the camera app, which is a server app).
In fact, the old file Uri scheme is banned for the apps with targetSDKVersion of 24 and higher (that was exactly the one I targeted); starting from that target SDK, the developer should use a File Provider in order to manage files from one app to another.

I followed some online tutorials and articles, like the following:

- https://rahulupadhyay.wordpress.com/2016/12/27/android-n-fileuriexposedexception/.

Here I will try to explain all the important modifications made for having an app that works also for these API (Nougat).

**Strings added in the AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<!-- The following component is a file provider needed from target Version Android API 24 (Nougat) and on
       -->
       <provider
           android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
           android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
           android:exported="false"
           android:grantUriPermissions="true">
           <meta-data
               android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
               android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
       </provider>
```

**Use of "provider_paths.xml"**

In the res Folder, I've created a "xml" folder where I created the following .xml file named "provider_paths.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--In this file we specify the list of storage area and path in XML, using child elements of the <paths> element.
These paths are used by the provider set in the manifest
The <paths> element must contain one or more of the following child elements: "<files-path name="name" path="path" /> Represents files in the files/ subdirectory of your app's internal storage area. This subdirectory is the same as the value returned by Context.getFilesDir()."
For example, the following paths element tells FileProvider that you intend to request content URIs for the images/ subdirectory of your private file area.-->

<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="my_images"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

**Modification of SinglePhotoShooting.java**

Also the java file "SinglePhotoShooting.java" has been modified, but the most important modifications are the ones regarding the "SPSATakePhoto" method, mostly when the "FileProvider.getUriForFile" function is called.

```
public void SPSATakePhoto(View view) {
//        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SinglePhotoShooting,
//                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Beginning of Take Photo");
        Intent callCameraApplicationIntent = new Intent();
        callCameraApplicationIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        // We give some instruction to the intent to save the image
        File photoFile = null;

        try {
            // If the createImageFile will be successful, the photo file will have the address of the file
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            // Here we call the function that will try to catch the exception made by the throw function
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Exception error in generating the file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Here we add an extra file to the intent to put the address on to. For this purpose we use the FileProvider, declared in the AndroidManifest.
        Uri outputUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                this,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                photoFile);
        callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);
        // The following is a new line with a trying attempt
        callCameraApplicationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Calling the camera App by intent");

        // The following strings calls the camera app and wait for his file in return.
        startActivityForResult(callCameraApplicationIntent, ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP);
    }
```

I also modified the "MainMenu.java" file for allowing the app to run on Lollipop (as you can read in the original post, the app used to crash due to permission managing not supported in Lollipop), with the older permission system at install time (rather than the newer system "on run-time" supported from Marshmallow and on) but for this I'll let you check it out directly in the repository because these modifications doesn't cover the purpose of the original question.

Here you can find the repository with the app and the corresponding modifications to make it work:

https://github.com/AlessandroIu/photosavingapp